# Creating a new menu item that links to /user

Tags: 7, routes

How do I format an array item using `hook_menu()` that links to /user but has a new title and is only accessible to logged in users?

Currently I'm using

```
    $items['user'] = array(
      'title' => 'Account Settings',
      'path' => 'user',
      'router_path' => 'user',
      'description' => 'Manage your username, password and contact information here.',
      'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
      'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
      'weight' => -20,
    );
```

Then end goal is to have a link that is titled 'Account Settings' that links to /user and that is only available to logged in users.

Edit: I guess to clarify, how can I incorporate the system menu `/user` item into my modules menu without using the UI?

Comment: What do you mean by "my modules menu"?

Comment: Sorry, that was confusing. :) I meant 'in the menu created by my custom module.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to duplicate the /user path, then you can use define the following menu item in the implementation of `hook_menu()` in your module:

```
  $items['your module path'] = array(
    'title' => 'User account', 
    'description' => 'Manage your username, password and contact information here.',    'title callback' => 'user_menu_title', 
    'page callback' => 'user_page', 
    'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM, 
    'file' => 'user.pages.inc',
    'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'user'),
  );
```

Replace "your module path" with the path used by your module, which cannot be the path already used by another module.

If you just want to alter the existing /user path, and avoid is accessible to everybody, then you need to implement [hook_menu_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) using code similar to the following:

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  if (isset($items['user'])) {
    $items['user']['access callback'] = 'user_is_logged_in';
  }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely awesome.  I didn't realize you could set the file like that.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To move an existing menu item to a different menu in code, you can implement [hook_menu_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) and change menu_name and weight for `$items['user']`.

Answer (score 1):

$items['user'] is already defined by user.module - menu items must be unique, so you can't redeclare it in your hook.

Is there a reason you can't use the "My Account" item supplied by the user module?  You can override the title on the menu admin page.

Comment: That would work perfectly.  Only I would need to be able to bring that link into my custom menu (say, at a weight of -20) that would be available upon enabling my custom module.  How can I insert $items['user'] into my custom menu? Thank you by the way. :)

Comment: Simply edit the My account link and set your custom menu as the parent. That's it. You do not need to mess with hook_menu() with move/add/alter menu links to *existing* router items.

Comment: Can I do this through a module rather than the UI?

Comment: You can implement hook_menu_alter() and then just set the menu_name and weight for $items['user'], yes. See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7

Comment: @Berdir That is exactly what I was looking for.  Would accept as answer if I could. ;)

Comment: @Berdir That would be an answer.